# Using multiple values in SQL query where clause

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

```
Select Distinct
  SomeDay.SomeDayID, SomeDay.FolderName, SomeDay.FolderColor
from
  SomeDay, SomeDayEvent
where
  SomeDay.SomeDayID != 4,3,2,1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use `!=` for multiple values for that you should use `not in` like:

```
Select Distinct 
    SomeDay.SomeDayID,SomeDay.FolderName,SomeDay.FolderColor 
from 
    SomeDay,SomeDayEvent 
where 
    SomeDay.SomeDayID not in (4,3,2,1);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't separate values in the WHERE part by comma. You have to use the IN or BETWEEN keyword.

```
SomeDay.SomeDayID NOT IN (1,2,3,4)
```

or

```
SomeDay.SomeDayID NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 4
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select Distinct SomeDay.SomeDayID,SomeDay.FolderName,SomeDay.FolderColor from SomeDay,SomeDayEvent where SomeDay.SomeDayID NOT IN (4, 3, 2, 1)`

Use the IN clause.

Answer (score 0):

Is `SomeDayID` nullable? You should be aware that the expression

```
NULL NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

does not evaluate to TRUE.